How do I implement a scheduled task for file transfer with different start/end time and cleanup?
I find myself in somewhat of a slump with the program I am trying to create. I was given the task of automating a file transfer from one folder to another using C#. I have four source folders, let's name them S1, S2, S3, and S4 for now, and four destination folders, D1, D2, D3, and D4. S1 transfers files to D1 based on the day of the week. Inside D1, there are folders with the names of the days of the week, and S1 transfers the files to D1 based on the the current day of the week. Say that today is Tuesday, then S1 will transfer the files to the folder "Tuesday" inside D1. After a week, the contents of these folders are deleted, again, based on their respective day of the week. The same thing happens for S2 which is mapped to D2.
Now, for S3, this is a different scenario. S3 transfers files to D3 weekly and creates a folder with the current date as the name. After a week, a new folder will be created with that day's date and S3 will transfer its files to that newly created folder. After a month, these folders will be deleted based on the date they were created. Finally, S4 is just a direct file transfer to D4 with a monthly cleanup.
Also, the file transfer is triggered on different time of the day. S1 begins its task from 12 midnight to 12NN, S2 from 12NN to 7PM, S3 from 7PM to 12NN, and S4 only transfers files on Mondays from 12 midnight to 12NN.
I initially tried creating a class that holds the source and destination path, start and end time, date of cleanup, and date exceptions. This class also performs the transfer itself based on the time and date but I suddenly realized that I don't have any way of checking the cleanup date and time for the subfolders. I'd really appreciate any insight on this. Thanks!

Please provide more details regarding operating system, type of C# application, etc.. Otherwise you get dozens of "the best way is ..." answers, which may be the "worst" for you.

Best way is to use some kind of scheduler app which will start your class to perform the action.
There are many such as

Quartz.net
FluentScheduler
Cronos
Hangfire
and many more

I have used HandFire in the past.  Below is an example of how to launch a recurring Job, but there are different types.
var scheduleString = $"*/5 6-21 * * *"; //every 5 minutes between 6-21
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Job Name", () => AsyncMethodToExecuteJob(param1, stoppingToken), scheduleString, AppSettings.HangFireOptions);


 public static readonly RecurringJobOptions HangFireOptions = new()
 { 
     TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(AppConstants.TimeZoneName) 
 };

public async Task AsyncMethodToExecuteJob(MyClass param1, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
   //blah blah
}

I used it in a HostedService in ASP.NET (Core).  To set up it up I done the following:
services.AddHangfire(c => c.UseMemoryStorage());
services.AddHangfireServer();

I used an inmemory storage, but you can store using almost any database if you wish.
There is also a dashboard made available so you can view the status of the jobs and any errors etc. and relaunch them.
To use this you need to add
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
      // Map Dashboard to the `http://<your-app>/hangfire` URL.
      app.UseHangfireDashboard();
  }

So in your case, you can define the schedule you want.  If necessary you can launch your the same Class at different schedules, or you could have different classes called.
